# SimpleXML Output as a String

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML File for an API. The API responses everytime "Errormesage: Expected argument of type "string", "array" given".

```
$SimpleXML_loaded_File = simplexml_load_file("http://graphics.edc-internet.nl/b2b_feed.php?key=tc62te28wt3e2t73ctr9c1cw42601337&sort=xml&type=xml&lang=de");

foreach ($SimpleXML_loaded_File->product as $product) {

  /*$client->post('articles', array(
      'name' => $product->titel,
      'taxId' => 1,
      'supplier' => $product->merk,
      'mainDetail' => array(
          'number' => $product->artikelnummer
      )
  ));*/

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($product->artikelnummer);
echo "</pre>";

}
```

If i var_dump the Output i dont get a string i`m getting the object

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "0633178"
}
```

How do i get only the string ?

Comment: [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump) is not asking for a string value specifically, so you might just have chosen the wrong function. You might haven been looking for [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval) instead. Or many of the other string functions in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SimpleXML is simple for a reason. When echoing an element, it automatically converts the object to a string. You can also explicitly cast it to one:

```
echo (string)$product->artikelnummer;
```

Comment: But why do i get the error message:Errormesage: Expected argument of type "string", "array" given.
As i said i get the value with 

$product->artikelnummer;

But the API says it`s an array.

Comment: @user3633186 You have to cast your `number` parameter to a string: `'number' => (string)$product->artikelnummer`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to type casting. Please check.

```
echo (string)$product->artikelnummer;
```